# Trying to create custom array adapter

Tags: java, android

So here im trying to create an custom array adapter , that can change images too, but when I do this it gives me error:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String [] food_text,int [] food_image) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row,food_text,food_image);
}
```

But if I do this, it doesn't :

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String [] food_text) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row,food_text);
}
```

Here is my full code for custom adaptor:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

int[] food_image;

public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String [] food_text, int[] food_image) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row,food_text);
    this.food_image=food_image;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View foodView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);


    String singleFoodItem = (String) getItem(position);
    int SingleFoodImage = (int) getItem(position);
    TextView Food_text = (TextView) foodView.findViewById(R.id.Food_text);
    ImageView food_image = (ImageView) foodView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);

    Food_text.setText(singleFoodItem);
    food_image.setImageResource(SingleFoodImage);





    return foodView;
}
```

}

And I get this error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'super(android.content.Context,int,java.lang.String[],int[])'

Comment: Sounds to me like the super you're calling doesn't accept an int[] parameter at the end

Comment: So where  can I add an int[] parameter?

Comment: Im using a constructor for a custom ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` has specific constructors who's signature is defied in [`docs`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

since your constructor has no match against any of above , hence the error

so if you want some extra reference then use

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
     int [] food_image;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String [] food_text,int [] food_image) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row,food_text);
        this.food_image=food_image;
      }
  }
```

---

We passed the `String` array `String [] food_text` and you cannot convert it to `int` here

```
int SingleFoodImage = (int) getItem(position); // error, string can't be converted to int
```

So use this

```
int SingleFoodImage = food_image[position];
//  use the food_image

food_image.setImageResource(SingleFoodImage);
```

---

Update : if you are planning to apply filtering soon or later then you will face issues with images position array mismatch so we need to create a `POJO` class

1.) Create a class

```
class Food{
    private int imageID;
    private String text;
    public Food(){}
    public Food(String oText ,int oImage ){ text=oText; imageID=oImage;}
    // getters and setters 
    public int getImageID(){ return imageID;}
    public String getText(){ return text;}
}
```

2.) Create a list of `POJO` objects and use this adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Food> {

   public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Food> items) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row,items);
      }

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View foodView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);

    Food singleFoodItem = getItem(position);
    TextView Food_text = (TextView) foodView.findViewById(R.id.Food_text);
    ImageView food_image = (ImageView) foodView.findViewById(R.id.food_image);

    Food_text.setText(singleFoodItem.getText());
    food_image.setImageResource(singleFoodItem.getImageID());
    return foodView;
}}
```

example to create list

```
List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();
foods.add(new Food("Mango",R.drawable.image1));
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! But it keeps giving me another error, I have updated the post , can you get what im doing wrong ?

Comment: This implementation is bad, every one with basic android knowledge would know that it will not work with filtering. you should never store the data by your own if you are using ArrayAdapter...

Comment: @Selvin yes agreed , for filtering , the image positions array indexes won't be helpful although filtering isn't one of the mentioned requirements so i picked the easy solution , let me update it and thanks from the future readers and from me as well

Comment: Right solution is pojo with int and string properties or custom adapter based on BaseAdapter